# DnD 5E +1 Arrow and +1 Bow = +2 Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I know its a stupid question, but does the enchantment stack? so if I fire an +1 arrow from my +1 longbow, do I get +2 on attack roll and damage?

If not, what are +1 arrows good for if I already got an +1 longbow?